# Print only longest non-overlapping ranges from list

Tags: python, list

I need to choose many different non-overlapping ranges from a list.

data:

```
data = [
    "5628-6203",
    "4753-5325",
    "4690-5322",
    "4684-4923",
    "5652-6191",
    "5628-6203",
    "5628-6203", 
    "5628-6203",
    "17333-17563",
    "17333-17569",
    "17333-17557"
]
```

code:

```
# Parsing and sorting the data
ranges = [tuple(map(int, item.split('-'))) for item in data]
ranges.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

# Finding the longest non-overlapping ranges
non_overlapping_ranges = []
current_range = ranges[0]

for r in ranges[1:]:
    # Check for overlap
    if r[0] <= current_range[1]:
        # Merge overlapping ranges
        current_range = (current_range[0], max(current_range[1], r[1]))
    else:
        # Add the previous range to the result
        non_overlapping_ranges.append(current_range)
        # Move to the next range
        current_range = r

# Add the last range
non_overlapping_ranges.append(current_range)

# Sorting by range length and getting the longest ranges
longest_ranges = sorted(non_overlapping_ranges, key=lambda x: x[1] - x[0], reverse=True)

print(longest_ranges)
```

Expected output for data variable and what I expect in bigger data:

```
[(4690, 5322), (5628, 6203), (17333,17569)]
```

Comment: When you use a debugger, what is the *first* line that doesn't do what you expected?

Comment: If you didn't write this code yourself, where does it come from, and what did its author tell you when you asked them for support?

Answer (score 0):

> *"Print only longest non-overlapping ranges from list ...
>
>
>
>
> ... Expected output for data variable and what I expect in bigger data:*
>
> ```
> [(4690, 5322), (5628, 6203), (17333,17569)]
> ```

Correct me if I'm wrong; those values overlap, or are overlapped.

Here is a example.

```py
r = [tuple(map(int, e.split('-'))) for e in data]
for i, (x, a) in enumerate(r):
    for j, (y, b) in enumerate(r):
        if i == j: continue
        if x <= y:
            if x == y or a in range(y, b + 1):
                print((x, a), 'overlaps', (y, b))
```

Output

```
(5628, 6203) overlaps (5628, 6203)
(5628, 6203) overlaps (5628, 6203)
(5628, 6203) overlaps (5628, 6203)
(4690, 5322) overlaps (4753, 5325)
(4684, 4923) overlaps (4753, 5325)
(4684, 4923) overlaps (4690, 5322)
(5628, 6203) overlaps (5628, 6203)
(5628, 6203) overlaps (5628, 6203)
(5628, 6203) overlaps (5628, 6203)
(5628, 6203) overlaps (5628, 6203)
(5628, 6203) overlaps (5628, 6203)
(5628, 6203) overlaps (5628, 6203)
(5628, 6203) overlaps (5628, 6203)
(5628, 6203) overlaps (5628, 6203)
(5628, 6203) overlaps (5628, 6203)
(17333, 17563) overlaps (17333, 17569)
(17333, 17563) overlaps (17333, 17557)
(17333, 17569) overlaps (17333, 17563)
(17333, 17569) overlaps (17333, 17557)
(17333, 17557) overlaps (17333, 17563)
(17333, 17557) overlaps (17333, 17569)
```